# Why does inf2cat fail with Windows DDK 8.1?

Tags: driver, wdk

I'm trying to sign a driver using the Windows DDK 8.1 and VS 2013, but I am continually getting the same error. However, when I attempt to do the same with DDK 8.0 it works just fine.

To make sure it wasn't something that I had done I downloaded a [sample driver from MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Windows-8-Driver-Samples-5e1aa62e) and attempted to build that. The downloaded sample results in the same error.

Here's sample output from using the 8.0 kit version:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits>8.0\bin\x86\Inf2Cat.exe /os:8_x64 "/driver:C:\code\NDIS\C++\x64\Win8Release\package"

..................................................
Signability test complete.

Errors:
None

Warnings:
None

Catalog generation complete.
C:\code\NDIS\C++\x64\Win8Release\package\netvmini60.cat
C:\code\NDIS\C++\x64\Win8Release\package\netvmini620.cat
C:\code\NDIS\C++\x64\Win8Release\package\netvmini630.cat
```

Here's the exact same command using the 8.1 kit (wrapping added for readability):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits>8.1\bin\x86\Inf2Cat.exe /os:8_x64 "/driver:C:\code\NDIS\C++\x64\Win8Release\package"

......................
The integrity check for the Windows file protection data file
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\WindowsProtectedFiles.xml'
has failed. This is most likely due to a modification of the file's contents.
To fix the problem, obtain a valid copy of the file from Microsoft, restore
the file to its original state, or reinstall the application.
Signability test failed.
```

When I use Visual Studio I get the following error:

```
TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files
(x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\inf2cat.exe" /os:7_x64 /driver:C:\code\NDIS\C++
x64\Win7Release\package\". The handle is invalid.
```

I have checked the contents of the `WindowsProtectedFiles.xml` file that was mentioned in the error and it would appear that the file hasn't changed between 8.0 and 8.1. I have searched for another version but haven't been able to find anything. Reinstalling the DDk doesn't fix anything either.

Can anyone offer some insights as to why this is happening and how I might fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever solve your problem?

Comment: No I'm afraid I didn't. I can't find any detail on it anywhere. I have given up on it for now, though I would love for someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, please report back if you hear anything. This problem is driving me nuts. I haven't found anything useful... just old Microsoft support threads saying the "bug was fixed".

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread, but did anyone ever fix this issue? I'm trying to get into driver development and I can't create a driver without this being resolved and this is the only post that comes up regarding inf2cat.exe

Comment: Still a negative I'm afraid. I haven't looked into it for quite some time though.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a reasonable workaround. Technically this is not an answer to your question but the result does yield a fully operational driver deployment from visual studio 2013.

I ended up just symlinking the x86 8.0 version of inf2cat to the 8.1 x86 directory and now everyone is happy and I can get on with my life.

Just run mklink as administrator (be sure to make a backup copy of the 8.1 version of inf2cat):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86>mklink Inf2Cat.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows   Kits\8.0\bin\x64\Inf2Cat.exe"

symbolic link created for Inf2Cat.exe <<===>> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x64\Inf2Cat.exe
```